# how to convert x-www-form-urlencoded payload to json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, hapi.js

i am using the npm [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to post data.
by default the posy is of `x-www-form-urlencoded`
so on the server side i am receiving the data like this

```
{
  'files[0][path]': 'myfile1',
  'files[0][contents]': 'some content',
  'files[0][active]': 'true'
}
```

how do i parse the data to json?
like

```
{
  files: [{
    path: 'mypath',
    content: 'mycontent',
    active: true
  } {
    path: 'mypath2',
    content: 'mycontent2',
    active: false
  }]
}
```

I think express js might use a middle wire for this, but I am using [hapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi) server.
what are my options to parse the payload to json?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of existing node packages that deal with parsing requests. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-json. To write a solution from scratch would just be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into jQuery's serializeArray() api? This might be good enough depending on your use case but [here's another library](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) built on top of serializeArray().

Answer (score 0):

with bodyparsing on the server side and hapijs, i happen to bump into [hapi-bodyparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-bodyparser) which did the job.